# How can I solve the problem of optimisation the quantum computer?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, optimization

I am trying to solve the problem of optimization (VRP) with genetic algorithm and quantum computing in the platform IBM Q Experience.
But I am unable to advance on this. How can I do it?
According to my understanding of quantum computing, we cannot apply the two processes of crossover and mutation in their classic sense.

Comment: Hi Aicha! Is there a paper you're referencing? Most likely the experiments you want to run will be difficult given the available hardware, but some may be feasible

Comment: D-Wave's hardware is better for VRP optimization problems, than IBM's. Many people already have done similar optimization problems on the D-Wave hardware, including Volkswagen. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this paper: [Ising formulations of many NP problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843). It deals with binary optimization on quantum annealers (e.g. D-Wave). As mentioned in comments, quantum annealers are more suitable for optimization tasks in comparison with gate-based universal quantum computers like IBM Q.

[Here](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/doc_getting_started.html) you can find something more about D-Wave, how it works and how it can be programmed.